# GitLab and Prometheus failure

Tags: centos, gitlab, prometheus

Setup: **GitLab** installed with **Omnibus** package on **CentOS** 6.4

After I've made a change in the GitLab configuration file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to configure Bitbucket as OAuth2 provider, I've run the reconfiguration:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

After I've launched this command I've seen some error, maybe about a monitoring service, but the SSH session drop and I haven't seen what happened.
After restoring the session GitLab was not accessible, I was able to see the GitLab logo with a 502 error: "**GitLab is taking too much time to respond**" or something similar.

So I've restored the configuration file, thinking something was wrong in it...

Running tail I've got the below errors (Prometheus is failing):

```
2018-01-30_22:19:19.28021 time="2018-01-30T23:19:19+01:00" level=info msg="Starting prometheus (version=, branch=, revision=)" source="main.go:87"
2018-01-30_22:19:19.28027 time="2018-01-30T23:19:19+01:00" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.9.2, user=, date=)" source="main.go:88"
2018-01-30_22:19:19.28030 time="2018-01-30T23:19:19+01:00" level=info msg="Host details (Linux 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 18 19:25:05 UTC 2016 x86_64 lnx01.brainsen.com (none))" source="main.go:89"
2018-01-30_22:19:19.29486 time="2018-01-30T23:19:19+01:00" level=info msg="Loading configuration file /var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml" source="main.go:254"
2018-01-30_22:19:19.29779 time="2018-01-30T23:19:19+01:00" level=error msg="Could not open the fingerprint-to-metric index for archived series. Please try a 3rd party tool to repair LevelDB in directory "/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data/archived_fingerprint_to_metric". If unsuccessful or undesired, delete the whole directory and restart Prometheus for crash recovery. You will lose all archived time series." source="persistence.go:213"
2018-01-30_22:19:19.29781 time="2018-01-30T23:19:19+01:00" level=error msg="Error opening memory series storage: leveldb: manifest corrupted (field 'comparer'): missing [file=MANIFEST-000923]" source="main.go:192"
```

I've run the command

```
sudo -u gitlab-prometheus python -c "import leveldb; leveldb.RepairDB('/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data/archived_fingerprint_to_metric')"
```

but I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named leveldb
```

Now GitLab is working fine but running tail I still see the above error about Prometheus every 2 seconds and I'd like to fix it without breaking my GitLab installation.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is gitlab runs Prometheus in a pyvenv setup which I can't find where it is.

You can always

```
pip install leveldb
```

And then run the command.. it should work

Comment: Hi Mike, I'll try this as soon as I can touch the machine. Now I need it 100% working for a code review to win a tender... and if I broke it... I'll keep you update if it works